# Typescript dynamically generate variable name

Tags: typescript, dynamic

I need to dynamically create variable instances and assign values in single statement as below.

```
this.myList1[data.id] = data.id + "-" + data.desc;
this.myList2[data.id] = data.id + "-" + data.desc;
this.myList3[data.id] = data.id + "-" + data.desc;
this.myList4[data.id] = data.id + "-" + data.desc;
this.myList5[data.id] = data.id + "-" + data.desc;
this.myList6[data.id] = data.id + "-" + data.desc;
```

Can someone suggest me what is the best way to do this in Typescript?

Comment: Since your variables are dynamic, maybe try using an _array_ or a _map_ to store your values?

Comment: @molamk can you please provide an example? In case I already have a Map

Answer (score 0):

Use template string literals and bracket notation syntax with `this`:

```
myList.forEach((data: object, index: number) => {
    this[`myList${index + 1}`][data.id] = `${data.id}-${data.desc}`;
});
```

Comment: I don't have myList as a variable. So I can't iterate through myList